# wxExecute can't execute file that needs admin permissions UAC

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, nsis

From ***wxWidgets*** application I try to run installer, made with ***NSIS***, in silent mode (**/S** flag). Got this error:

> Execution of command: "C:\somecommand.exe" failed (error 0: Операция
>   завершена успешно / Successful).

When I run installer silently from command line, I got UAC popup, but when I execute it from wxWidget application I got only this error. And what this error means? Like "Fatal Error: All is fine".

In NSIS script I have ***RequestExecutionLevel admin***, because I really need it to have ability to install program in directories like Program Files.

Comment: Which flags do you pass to `wxExecute()`? It works both with `wxEXEC_SYNC` and `wxEXEC_ASYNC` in wxWidgets "exec" sample for me with an installation program I have here, i.e. it launches and shows the UAC dialog. Also, which version of wx do you use?

Comment: wxEXEC_ASYNC by default, so I passed no flags. wxWidgets 3.0.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a Windows application that requires elevation you must use [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) and not [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), CreateProcess will just fail with a elevation required error.

I would imagine that `wxLaunchDefaultApplication` uses `ShellExecute` internally but it seems a bit risky to rely on that so you might as well use a ifdef:

```
#ifdef __WINDOWS__  // __WXMSW__
ShellExecute(0, 0, pathtoexe, parameters, 0, SW_SHOW);
#else
wxExecute(something);
#endif
```